# How to store a face in memory

Tags: java, memory, opengl-es, 3d

Ive been trying to figure this out but cant find a way to do it which seems reasonable, and nothing seems to actually explain it, I can find a myriad of stuff on how to do modelling, and how to work withthe faces, but nothing on whow they can be stored in memory to work with. Ive been looking at obj mainly, and the rest is easy it's mainly just arrays to store it all, but faces, the only way Ive been able to think of to work with them is to store the details on which vertices   in an object, or to read them from file each time, but that can't be right surely? It seems crazy to be using an object for every face, but I cant think of any other way!
Even just a book to look at or anything to just point me in the right direction, because everything just seems to skip over this stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A face is usually three or more vertices connected. This means you can store each face as a list of the vertices (or indices to the vertices) it consists of.

```
f0: [v0 v1 v2]
f1: [v3 v4 v5] 
...
```

Or if the amount of vertices for each face is predetermined (which I would wager is common), you could collapse it into a single list/vector/array:

```
[/* face 1 */ v0 v1 v2 /* face 2 */ v3 v4 v5]
```

[Wikipedia may convey it better than I do.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh#Face-vertex_meshes)

Comment: I got this, it was more the extra stuff it has, theyve all got textures and stuff associated with them too. Unless Im missing something this needs to be stored with each face?

Comment: I guess it depends on your needs but such information is usually stored at a vertex level (at least when sending it to the hardware). If you can quickly lookup the vertices belonging to a face you can quickly find the data needed for texturing a face.

Comment: @AaronM: What I guess I'm trying to say is that all the info is stored with the vertices, or somewhere else but it is individual to each vertex, not to each face.

Comment: How Id been thinking about it that caused the same problem just changing it from how to store a face, to how to store a vertex. But your answer has passively made me realise a stupidly obvious way to do it, so thank you :)

Comment: @AaronM: Hehe, no problem. You could make an object for each Vertex, or if you wanna squeeze bytes I guess you could pack it into block of bytes (possibly resembling what you would send to OpenGL.) You could also maintain several arrays where the index would represent the vertex and the arrays different types of data, although it sounds a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is arrays of vertices. How it works is each object contains an array of vertices and a color. The normals for the vertices are stored in this same array, (vertexX, vertexY, vertexZ, normalX, normalY, normalZ). When you want to render your objects, you loop through your array of objects and render each object as shown below:

```
float plane[] = {
    10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    -10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    -10, -10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    -10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    10, -10, 0, 0, 0, 1,
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(plane[0])*6, &plane[0]);
glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(plane[0])*6, &plane[3]);

glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (sizeof(plane) / sizeof(plane[0]))/6);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

And that should draw a red plane. Only difference is you would want to feed it your array from your object definition. You can also include color information per vertex and just include a glColorPointer in the above code and a glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY).

Comment: It was less that problem than how to work on rendering something from a file, I'd been trying to hold information on a face that it turned out I hadn't needed to. Thank you though :)